# Some strange output on my command in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, cat, ls

I've written the following in the command:

```
$ cat /bin/ls > blah
$ cat blah blah blah > bbb
$ chmod u+x bbb
$ ./bbb
```

And it printed all the file names in the current working directory.

My question is why? and why not 3 times?

Comment: You essentially made a copy of the `ls` executable, with a bunch of extra garbage at the end (extra copies of the executable).  Then you ran the copy... which listed files and exited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Linux executable file format ([ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)) is not a script that you can copy-paste three times in a row to get the same result. To be more precise, the header contains a single entry point (think of it as the address of where `int main()` has been stored), which is where the instructions are read from. Once you reach the final `return 0;` or whatever, the program stops, even if there is more (nicely structured) binary garbage following in the binary file.

TL;DR: Don't forget - `/bin/ls` is a compiled binary and not a shell script.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that it's an already complied file. Now it's clear, thanks!